# Is kafka consumer 0.10 backwards compatible?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is the kafka consumer 0.10 compatible with 0.9 broker?

If I'm not mistaken the 0.9 consumer is still considered beta whereas 0.10 is stable, right? That's why I'm interested in using the 0.10 version but my broker version is 0.9 and I wouldn't like to upgrade that yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to use 0.10 clients you need to upgrade your cluster to 0.10.

Kafka is backward compatible with regards to clients but not forward compatible. That is, a 0.9 client can use a 0.10 cluster but a 0.10 client can not use a 0.9 cluster.

The idea is to upgrade your cluster first to 0.10, and then gradually migrating clients from 0.9 to 0.10.

Comment: Ok, this sounds reasonable. Is there any documentation that mentions this? Have you tried it yourself? Thanks

Comment: It is implicitly documented here https://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html#protocol_compatibility. "The server will reject requests with a version it does not support, and will always respond to the client with exactly the protocol format it expects based on the version it included in its request." And yes, I have tested both cases using kafka-console-consumer.sh with --new-consumer flag. That is using new Java consumer.

Comment: Does it matter if the kafka broker is using scala 2.11 but the kafka client/producer is using scala 2.12? It seems to work but just wanted to check?

Comment: It should not matter since the important things here are the version of the wire protocol that is being used by clients and the protocol versions supported by the brokers.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is not only for `0.10.0` client. I search `Kafka client & broker version compatibility` and reach here, so I leave a more complete answer for future reader.

According to [this official post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/upgrading-apache-kafka-clients-just-got-easier/):

> The “bidirectional” client compatibility work done in KIP-35 and KIP-97 removed these limitations. New Java clients can now communicate with old brokers.
>
> Improved client compatibility is a new feature in Kafka 0.10.2. It is supported by brokers that are at version 0.10.0 or later.

For example, if we use client in `2.0.0`, we can use broker `0.10.0` and **all** other later version (and of course, new feature will not supported). But if we use client in `0.10.1`, we can only communicate with broker from `0.10.1` and later version.

So, kafka consumer `0.10` **is not** compatible with `0.9` broker.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what language your client is written in and which client libraries you are using. Some clients (like those based on librdkafka) can handle connections to an older broker but the general rule (which is also true for the default Apache kafka java clients) is that the broker must be of equal or higher version number than the clients. In other words, Kafka is backward compatible, but it is not yet fully forward compatible.

Comment: Yes, I meant the new Java consumer API. Thanks for pointing it out.