# Is Kafka 0.10 compatible with Spark 1.6.2?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

If I use Spark 1.6.2, Scala 2.10 and `spark-streaming-kafka_2.10`, can I consume messages from Kafka 0.10.1.0 from Scala code? (there is a remote machine with Kafka 0.10.1.0, inter broker protocol version: 0.10.1.0, and Scala 2.11). Or does it imply that I should use Spark 2.*?

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I read this text in some forums and it confused me a lot:

```
Kafka 0.10 support is only coming with Spark 2.0 on Scala and Java workloads
```

For instance, to consume messages, Scala does not process Kafka queue parameters (broker list, zookeeper ip, etc.), but it just sends them directly to Kafka, which interprets them. Is it correct? In this case, why Kafka 0.10 does not support Spark 1.6.2?

UPDATE:

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238239/is-kafka-consumer-0-10-backwards-compatible) I understand that it's possible to use Kafka that I specified in POM (see above) in order to consume messages from Kafka 0.10.1.0, but not sure. What does `Kafka client` mean? Does it mean Kafka installed on remote server (i.e. Kafka 0.10.1.0) or does it mean my Kafka that I specified in POM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.10.1.0[image: picture]
It depends on the kafka version you installed.the official offers two binary for each version.if you installed scala 2.10,you should install Scala 2.10  - kafka_2.10-0.10.1.0.tgz ,otherwise Scala 2.11  - kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.tgz 
[the official documents](http://kafka.apache.org/downloads)

Comment: Just to be sure I uderstand it correctly: If there is Kafka 0.10.1.0 and Scala 2.11 installed on remote cluster, it is not recommended to consume messages from the topics of this cluster using Scala 2.10, right? Please notice that my Consumer's code is executed on AWS machine, not on the machine where Kafka cluster runs.

Comment: Oh, in this condition , it may be ok.